# Magento checkout success page: If an item in the order is not returnable, display message

Tags: php, magento, orders

I sell load bearing equipment and underwear, both of these we don't want returns on (for health & safety issues). We have set up in `catalog\product\view.phtml` to check for isReturnable and if it isn't, it displays an error message.
 This only affects the item detail view.
 I would also like to display this information on the onepage sucess page.

So far the function i'm trying to use is:

```
<?php
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$items = $order->getItemsCollection();
foreach($items as $item){
$isReturnable = $item->getData('isReturnable');
} 
?>
<?php if (!$items->isReturnable()): ?>
<div class="shipping-message"><?php echo $this->__('Return exceptions apply to an item
in your order.'); ?> <a href="/return-exceptions/">Click here for details</a></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

When I try `(!$items->isReturnable()): ?>` it returns nothing, and when I try 
 `($items->isReturnable()): ?>` it returns nothing. (Should be not returnable, and returnable, just to test out the code).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to override the `root\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\success.phtml`

template file and use the above code directly for the same.

OR

You can also create a function e.g. isReturnable($orderId) in class  `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Success`

but don't modify the core block you need to override in your local module.

**[UPDATE]**

`$items->isReturnable();` code never return anything as you are try to get the property of an item on item collection, It will only worked with item object and this should be

`$item->getIsReturnable();`

So your code should be looks like

```
<?php
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$items = $order->getItemsCollection();
$isReturnable = false;
foreach($items as $item){
    $isReturnable = ($isReturnable)? $isReturnable : $item->getIsReturnable();
} 
?>

<?php if($isReturnable): ?>
    <div class="shipping-message"><?php echo $this->__('Return exceptions apply to an item
    in your order.'); ?> <a href="/return-exceptions/">Click here for details</a></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I'm already overidig the core files (without editing them), but not getting any valid code returned from the code I posted.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing:

```
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$items = $order->getItemsCollection();
$hasUnreturnable = false;
foreach($items as $item){
if (!$item->getProduct()->isReturnable()) {
$hasUnreturnable = true;
break;};
} ?>
<?php if ($hasUnreturnable): ?>
<p><div class="shipping-message"><?php echo $this->__('Return exceptions apply to an item in your order.'); ?> <a href="/return-exceptions/">Click here for details</a></div></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```